# What is better to use in Java? x <= 10 or x < 11?

Tags: java, performance

Is there any difference affecting program efficiency between `x <= 10`  and  `x < 11` ? Are there any other differences?

Thank you

Comment: i doubt it. we would be going into differences of probably pico seconds

Comment: both are same in terms efficiency.

Comment: Not enough difference to worry about, pick the one that most clearly shows what you are checking. e.g. for a collection loop, prefer `x < length` over `x <= length-1`.

Comment: What are the results of your tests of the two options ?  If the effort of testing them both exceeds your interest in the matter, and your question suggests that it does, then it's not worth your while bothering with any possible difference in performance.  Choose whichever expression better expresses your ideas and get on to some more interesting programming matters.

Comment: If there were a difference (there isn't), you could count on the compiler to replace x<=10 by x<11 for you where it does not change the program.

Comment: This is a clear example of optimization gone wrong.

Comment: Someone's downvoting every answer except the first... weird...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings
 For example, for `x <= 10` ,  `if_icmple`  instruction will be used and for  `x < 11` ,  `if_icmplt`  instruction will be used. Both should have same efficiency.

Comment: Good reference, but the byte codes used will depend on the compiler (may be if_icmpgt and if_icmpge).

Comment: Bytecode is irrelevant in reference to performance. It is the JITted code that matters, and it could be anything.

Answer (score 3):

No difference for program, I think this is more personal taste.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference for

```
int x;
(x <= 10) == (x < 11)
```

But for double there is huge difference:

```
double x = 10.5;
x <= 10 // is false
x < 11 // is true
```

Answer (score 2):

There should not be any difference at all. Same number of checks is performed

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you are doing . For example see below .

The  loop where `i <= 10` executes `101` time whereas `i < 11` executes `111` times.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int count = 0;
    for (double i = 0; i <= 10; i = i + 0.1)
        count++;

    System.out.println(count);
    count = 0;
    for (double i = 0; i < 11; i = i + 0.1)
        count++;
    System.out.println(count);

}
```

Output:

```
101
111
```

Comment: I suspect the downvoter assumed OP was talking about integers and simply looking for performance differences (not functional differences) (as most of us did) (but that wasn't explicitly stated though).

Answer (score 1):

Both are same in terms efficiency, **Its personal choice**.
If you check the byte **code** of generated class both has the **same complexity** i.e. for both the cases as the(suppose the checking present in a for loop) loop executed same no of times so they have the same complexity, so **it doesn't effect in the complexity of a program**.

Comment: I do not have the byte code right now. You can refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings. And thank you for showing interest on byte code :-)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of x. In case of an integer, there will be no difference.  If it's a `float` or a `double`, there's a definite difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

I tested a bit, here is the code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    boolean b;
    Date d = new Date();
    for (long i = 0; i < 10000000001L; i++) {
        b = i < 1000001L;
    }
    System.out.println("< " + ((new Date()).getTime() - d.getTime()) + " ms");
    d = new Date();
    for (long i = 0; i <= 10000000000L; i++) {
        b = i <= 1000000L;
    }
    System.out.println("<= " + ((new Date()).getTime() - d.getTime()) + " ms");
}
```

The results after 3 runs showing less than 1% difference or around it, that seems more like dependent on the current load of the computer. You can check it.

< 12680 ms
<= 12673 ms

< 12726 ms
<= 12717 ms

< 12624 ms
<= 12774 ms